# Regular Expression to extract information from SWIFT MT202 message

Tags: regex

In MT202, 58D can have first line optional. If there is no '/', it will take the first line as name.

```
:58D:/ABCD
NAME
ADDRESS 1
:72:XYZ
```

```
:58D:NAME
ADDRESS 1
:72:XYZ
```

Regular Expression I've prepare so far works fine but fails when ADDRESS 2 is not present. It gives  ADDRESS 1 instead of null value.

Here is the RegEx for ADDRESS 2

```
:58D:(?:\/.*\n)?(?:.*\n){2}(.*)\n:
```

Can anyone fix it or provide a better solution?